# How do I sanitize ILIKE query in Node-pg

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, postgresql

I'm trying to create a filter for a findAll function that filters by name. The other filters in this function work fine but I can't get the name filter to work.

The function below accepts filter parameters (if any) and adds on to the WHERE query based on any passed in filters. Right now, when I pass in a name, it returns nothing unless the query matches a name in the database but I'm trying to return results that contain whatever the value of `name` is (i.e. a name query for 'net' would get you 'Neural Networks')

Here is what I have so far:

```
static async findAll(searchFilters = {}) {
    let query = `SELECT handle, name, description, num_employees AS "numEmployees", logo_url AS "logoUrl"
           FROM companies`;
    let whereStatement = []
    let values = []
    const {name, minEmployees, maxEmployees} = searchFilters

    if (minEmployees > maxEmployees) throw new BadRequestError('minEmployees cannot be greater than maxEmployees!')
    
    if (!!minEmployees) {
      values.push(minEmployees)
      whereStatement.push(`num_employees >= $${values.length}`)
    }
    if (!!maxEmployees) {
      values.push(maxEmployees)
      whereStatement.push(`num_employees <= $${values.length}`)
    }
    if (!!name) {
      values.push(name)
      whereStatement.push(`name ILIKE $${values.length}`)
    }

    if (whereStatement.length > 0) {
      query += ` WHERE ${whereStatement.join(" AND ")}`
    }
    query += ' ORDER BY name'
    const companiesRes = await db.query(query, values)
    return companiesRes.rows;
  }
```

I tried typing it like this:

`name ILIKE '%$${values.length}%'`

but I got this message:

```
"error": {
    "message": "bind message supplies 1 parameters, but prepared statement \"\" requires 0",
    "status": 500
  }
```

Is there a specific way to sanitize ILIKE queries in Node-pg or is my syntax just off?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your code in place where you append the name filter should look like:

```js
...
    if (!!name) {
      values.push(`%${name}%`)
      whereStatement.push(`name ILIKE $${values.length}`)
    }
...
```

see [503#issuecomment-32055380](https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres/issues/503#issuecomment-32055380)

Comment: Wow, that was it. Thank you!